# TikZ: put caption into a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, tikz-node

I would like to put the caption of my figure into my node, something like

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) node {\caption{This is the caption}\label{fig}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 3):

just define `text width` for node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) node[text width=\linewidth] {\caption{This is the caption}\label{fig}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

**note**:
caption can be  only in text or in environments which support writting paragraph as are `parbox`, `minipage`, ...

if you define text width of node, than node's content has paragraph features

**addendum**
an example for more fancy looks of node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%--- show page layout, only for test, don't use in real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) node[
                draw=yellow!60,                 % border around node with defined color
                semithick,                      % border line thicknes
                fill=yellow!30,                 % color of node's fill 
                text width=\linewidth-          % with  of node, 
                                                % considered are inner xsep
                                                % and shadow xhift, with this it 
                                                % not spill out right text border
                                      2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}-4pt,
                text=black,                     % text color
                drop shadow={fill=orange,       % shodows with added defined option: 
                                                % color of the fill
                                                %% default values are:
                                                % shadow scale=1, 
                                                % shadow xshift=.5ex, shadow yshift=-.5ex,
                                                % opacity=.5, fill=black!50, every shadow
                            shadow xshift= 4pt, % shift to the right
                            shadow yshift=-4pt} % shift down (or with sign - up)
                             ] {\caption{This is the caption}\label{fig}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

for even more fancy styles you should consider package `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Thanks for this brilliantly simple solution. I have no idea how people are able to figure out what is wrong, for me Latex errors are unreadable. There is just one slight issue, I would like to put a white background (or sometimes a box) around the text. Giving the additional option `node[..., fill=white]` now fills the whole text width. Is there a better solution than adding another node displaying phantom text to draw the background?

Answer (score 2):

After trying for an hour I couldn't figure it out, 5 minutes later I come up with a solution...
Nevertheless here it is:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\nodecaption}[2]{\subcaptionbox{#1\label{#2}}{\phantom{(X)~#1}}}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) node {\nodecaption{This is the caption}{fig}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Far from optimal but it does the job.